# SVN hooks to link external application

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-hooks

Is there a possibility/way to give a hyperlink (or a reference to a particular link) inside the svn log message so that whenever i click that particular link I'm directed to an external application (such as Internet address to my custom bug tracking tool)

**For ex:** 
I insert a log message while committing my sources in SVN

```
Changes made to fix issue *#1234*
```

Now here, the *#1234* should appear as a hyperlink and should take me to an external application (say the internet address for my custom bug tracking tool)

Should i start using SVN post commit hooks ?
Please suggest whether this is possible

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can set a few properties on your root folder in the working copy and it will then work.
See the [docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-bugtracker.html) about this. It describes the properties you have to set very well.